# Add multiple GridView in the same scrollable layout/fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview, android-gridview

I know there are several questions for this problem already as I have searched for an hour, but neither of those has solved my problem nor the solution is too old.

I'm working on an event app and it displays the attendance of people going to it. It need to has two GridView: YES and NO, depending on the attendance, and it shows the picture of the guests.

I have already made the "YES" GridView and I tried adding a new TextView and GridView to my layout + getting the layout of it in Java for my "NO" GridView **but it only shows the first one.**

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Fragments for each of my tabs.

*This is what I have v.s. what I want:*

[image: This is my app, just showing one GridView:]
[image]

This is my fragment's layout:

```
[fragment_one.xml]

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.example.MainActivity.OneFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/title_yes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="14dp"
android:text="Yes"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular" />

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview_yes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_yes"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/title_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:text="No"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular" />

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview_no"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_no"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment's Java:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        GridView gridViewYes = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_yes);
        GridView gridViewNo = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_no);
        gridViewYes.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity()
        gridViewNo.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity()

    gridViewYes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Esta es la imagen " + position + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a RecyclerView with a layout manager like this https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM, is really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView is probably not your best option here.  That widget is intended to be used when you have a potentially long list of things to display in a scrolling container.  TableView is better when you have a manageable set of items that doesn't need its own scrolling behavior.

Also, you probably don't want a layout_height of match_parent for these things.  Use wrap_content to only let them be as tall as their content suggests.

If you need the whole thing to scroll because you aren't certain of the entire height, place the LinearLayout in a ScrollView and let that determine if the collection of tables and text should be scrollable if they're too tall for the space allotted.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Doug! I solved my problem changing the layout_height of GridView, what could affect my app if I let it as a GridView and not changing to TableLayout? Why do you say it is better?

Comment: Stacking multiple components that can scroll on their own (like GridView) can make the UI unusable if they become tall.  Maybe it works right now with a particular data set, but it may not work well in the future if you get more data and everything becomes taller than the available space.

Comment: Two last things Doug. 1. Will I need the TableLayout even if I use ScrollView to nest my LinearLayout with the two GridView or there will be problems still if GridViews gets too big? And 2. What do you think about using a different layout like GridLayout or multiple LinearLayouts?

Comment: Yes, GridLayout or multiple LinearLayout should be fine, as well as TableLayout.  Anything that does not try to handle its own scrolling.  The general rule is that you don't put scrolling views inside other scrolling views, otherwise it gets confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have set GridView yes height to match_parent.

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You should change as follows:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Simple but useful as hell, thank you very much sir, this was my problem!

Comment: Glad to help. Accept it as answer to help people with the same problem in the future.